# blocking function lookup on objects prototype for certain functions?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, backbone.js, prototype

I am trying to build a custom collection (lets call it GenericList), which can hold n collections and act like it was just one.

To inherit all the functions of an ordinary Backbone collection, I set the prototype of GenericList to a new instance of `Backbone.Collection`. Then I overwrite the important ones like `fetch()`, `reset()`, `on()`, `off()` and so on. Now there are also functions that I want to kick out of GenericList (basically add and create).

So in order to delete these functions, I first get my instances prototype which is `Backbone.Collection` and then Backbone.Collections prototype, which simply is an `Object` that holds all the collection functions. When I `delete` the functions from there, what happens is, that all instances of Backbone.Collection throughout my app loose these functions, because they all inherit from that one Object.

So my question is, are there other techniques than `delete` to hide a function on an object, even if that function is defined anywhere in the objects prototype chain?

edit: links [a fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/xmDsH/2/)  and [the thing on github](https://github.com/sra448/nested-models-in-backbone/blob/master/model.generics.js)

Comment: An actual code example demonstrating your problem would be nice; we could give more clear explanations and solutions that way.

Comment: sorry... https://github.com/sra448/nested-models-in-backbone/blob/master/model.generics.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accomplished exactly what I want by not inheriting from `new Backbone.Collection` but from `_.clone(Backbone.Collection.prototype)`. This way I have my own physical object as prototype and am able to delete whatever I want without it having an effect on other collections.

If you're interested in the code, I updated it on [github](https://github.com/sra448/nested-models-in-backbone/blob/master/model.generics.js) (row 114).

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's exactly how prototypes work in Javascript. When you reference a property inherited from a prototype in Javascript, what's actually happening is that Javascript looks for that property on the object itself first, and if it doesn't find it, it travels up the prototype chain to find the property. This happens at the time of the property lookup, and it happens on the actual prototype objects, not on an abstract prototype definition. So if you delete something from an object you're using as a prototype, then immediately following that you will no longer be able to reference that property, even in objects that inherit from that object.

To put it a different way, there's no such thing as a "class" and an "instance" in Javascript. There are only instances.

To do this properly, you need to delete the function from GenericList *after* creating it from Backbone.Collection. Otherwise you're actually modifying Backbone.Collection.

Comment: To clarify, I was explaining why "all instances of Backbone.Collection throughout my app lose these functions" ... It's because they're not "instances of Backbone.Collection" but rather objects that happen to have the single object Backbone.Collection as their prototype object

Comment: There is no function "add" on GenericList, but two stops down the prototype chain (meaning on GenericLists prototypes prototype). I cannot delete it there because of exactly what you wrote and am looking for another solution. I'm thinking of maybe just defining "add" on GenericList and throw an error, but I think we can do better than that.

Comment: How are you creating GenericList? (Again, code example!) This works for me: `var x = Object.create({a: 1}); delete x.a;`

Comment: You can take a look here [link](https://github.com/sra448/nested-models-in-backbone/blob/master/model.generics.js). On line 113 I inherit from Backbone.Collection, on line 26 I try to get rid of unwanted functions. I can simplify if you like.

Comment: The only thing I can think of without a large refactoring is to set "add" and "create" to null in your object. Unlike 'undefined', if a property is set to 'null' no prototype lookup will be performed (since it counts as an actual value).

Comment: assigning null or undefined both evaluate to their values, instead of looking up the prototype chain. I can't see the difference here. Anyway... I found a simple solution that involves setting the prototype to a clone of backbone.collections prototype. I will post it as a sepearete answer. Thanks anyway!